# Billboard.js get chart object using bb.instance via chart name (id)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, billboard.js

I am using Billboard.js and displaying multiple charts using `bb.generate`. Everything is working fine, I can get a `chart` object using `bb.instance[somenumber]`. This will get me a Billboard chart based on which number I give, respective to the order in which the charts were made using `bb.generate`. This works usually, except for cases when I'd like to grab a specific chart based on it's `bindto`, or the id associated with the div that is being used for `bb.generate`. Example below:

```
//chart gen
bb.generate({
      data: this.data,
      ...
      bindto: '#chartName', // --> This is what I want to grab a bb.instance by
    });

//html side:
<div id="chartName"></div>

// what I'd like to do:
var chart = bb.instance(#chartName); //or something like this 
chart.load(...)

//INSTEAD OF

var chart = bb.instance[0];
chart.load(...)
```

Is this possible? I'd like to have this functionality to easily grab separate chart instances and mess with them with ease, without having to worry about it's numbered order in the `bb.instance` array.

I have already investigated a few different ways to do this to no avail. The closest I can get to grabbing it is by going through the Chart object there is a private `_groups` object buried in `Chart.$.chart._groups[0][0].id`, which TypeScript is not very fond of (saying it doesn't exist).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If chart bound eleements has id attribute, which can be identified each of them, making some helper function will help.

```js
function getInstanceById(id) {
    return bb.instance.filter(v => v.$.chart.attr("id") === id)[0];
}

// will get chart instance bound to the <div id="chart">
getInstanceById("chart").load( ... );
```